# How to set wallpaper efficiently in Android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a problem with setting a wallpaper. My wallpaper image size is 18 mb (jpeg). I can set the wallpaper succesfully but it takes 12-15 seconds. It's very annoying. How do I set a wallpaper in 5-6 seconds or less?  I've been reading this for a week. I have a few ideas in my mind but I do not know how to do it.

I do not want to deteriorate or reduce the resolution. (I've tried sampleSize function but my resolution reduce)

- reduce image size (I dont know if that it is possible)
- use library ex: picasso, glide library (I dont know if this will work)
- save bitmaps less size (is it possible without losing quality?)

I'm so confused. I have shared a part of my code below.

```
int resIdWallpaper = res.getIdentifier(th.name + "_wallpaper","drawable",th.packageName);

   Bitmap drawableBitmap ;
   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    options.inSampleSize=1;
if (resIdWallpaper != 0) {
    drawableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resIdWallpaper, options);
    WallpaperManager wm= WallpaperManager.getInstance(mContext.getApplicationContext());

    try{

        wm.setBitmap(drawableBitmap);

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Wallpaper not set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should attempt to reduce the original image width and height. My guess is that you are using an image that is way to large. 18MB takes 12-15 seconds to download and view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you get you images from, but 18MB is way to much for a JPEG even in 4k resolution. Google has a lot material on every topic which could concern you application development. I suggest reading the article on [how to reduce image size](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/network-xfer.html)s. I myself wrote a [simple wallpaper application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ponysoft.animalwallpapercollection) several years ago. I don't ship the images with the app but only very small thumbnails. If a user wants the full resolution image its downloaded from my webserver. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help . It helps a lot.